# How to fill form in pdf with image for iText7?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have pdf with form inside it. I already can set form with value from text. But how if I want to fill the field with image instead with text?

Comment: The PDF standard does not have any form fields that accept images. In some contexts an "image field" is emulated by a push button with some specific JavaScript listeners. Is this what you have?

Comment: No. It is actually textfield. But I want to insert the image in that textfield position so instead of filled with text it will be filled with image

Comment: You cannot fill a text field with an image, it after all is a *text* field. You could instead add the image in another annotation or in the page content at the same position...

Comment: Yes. I want to do that. So I want to add image based on that textfield position but I can’t get how to do it in iTextPdf

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: nope. Deciding not using iText7.

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with a button, so add a button and insert an image into the button then replace the original formField with a button of the same Key and placement.

```
        formFields.TryGetValue(key, out var toSet);
        PdfArray sizingArray = toSet.GetWidgets()[0].GetRectangle();
        var width = (float)(sizingArray.GetAsNumber(2).GetValue() - sizingArray.GetAsNumber(0).GetValue());
        var height = (float)(sizingArray.GetAsNumber(3).GetValue() - sizingArray.GetAsNumber(1).GetValue());

        var imagbase64 = imaged.Draw(image);

        var button = PdfFormField.CreatePushButton(
            pdfDoc, new Rectangle(sizingArray.GetAsNumber(0).FloatValue(),
                sizingArray.GetAsNumber(1).FloatValue(),
                width,
                height), key, "");
        button.SetValue(imagbase64);

        form.ReplaceField(key, button);
```